# Factory functions that return classes (= class constructors) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

If I define a class in the following way in TypeScript

```
class A {}
```

then A is both a value and a type, so I can use it in both ways:

```
type B = A
const C = A
```

If A would be the result of a fancy class factory function instead:

```
const A = fancyClassFactory(...someArgs)
```

then A is only a value, NOT a type ...

Are there any ways to use such a class factory function and also get the type of the class?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If the factory returns `class extends Foo { ... }`  or `class implements IFoo { ... }` then you'll at least have a base class or common interface to refer to as its type outside the local scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A` is the constructor to the class you can use the `InstanceType` conditional to get the type of the instance:

```
const A = fancyClassFactory(...someArgs)
type A = InstanceType<typeof A>
```

For the specific example @daniel-hilgarth provided you could use conditional types so the return type is different according to the passed in constant:

```
function fancyClassFactory<T extends 'a' | 'b'>(what: T) : (T extends 'a' ? typeof fancyClassFactory.A: typeof fancyClassFactory.B) 
function fancyClassFactory(what: string) {
    if (what === 'a') {
        return  fancyClassFactory.A
    }
    if (what === 'b') {
        return fancyClassFactory.B
    }
}

namespace fancyClassFactory {
    export class A {
        foo() { return 'barA'; }
    }
    export class B {
        bar() { return 'fooB'; }
    }
} 
const A = fancyClassFactory('a');
const B = fancyClassFactory('b');
type TA = InstanceType<typeof A>;

function generic<T>(t: T) {
    console.log(t);
}

generic<TA>(new A());
generic<TA>(new B());
```

Comment: I think this is not correct. `InstanceType<typeof A>` will be the same no matter what concrete class will be returned by `fancyClassFactory`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zdLfRMRv -> The last line should result in an error but it doesn't

Comment: To be more precise, the result of `InstanceType<typeof A>` is all possible types that the class factory can return, e.g. `(Anonymous class) | (Anonymous class)` or `A | B | C`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth that is a problem with the definition of your factory since it returns a union of all posibil classes and does not have have any way of distinguish between when it's called with a or b

Comment: So how would you implement this? Can you provide a working example? I would say that this is impossible to achieve as the runtime decides which type is returned from the factory

Comment: @DanielHilgarth you can use conditional types. I will add a sample shortly

Comment: Great, looking forward to it. But this is a specific use case. There is no solution for an arbitrary `fancyClassFactory`, do you agree?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it depends. If we are talking about mixins/HOC the solution above works pretty well, depends on what specifically the factory does. If you have a real world example I can have a look and suggest something. Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot today :-) I don't have a use case, @Natasha asked the question, she might have.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth :)) I didn't notice you were not the OP